# QGIS - snapping points onto lines

Tags: qgis-plugins, vector, topology, digitizing, plugins

I have two layers, one is point layer and other one is a line layer. I want the point features to snap on to the lines, but the points are away from the lines. Is there any way to move the points onto lines?